# made a grid in css but it doesn't work

Tags: css

i'm trying to make a grid in css and the code i made is similar to almost all of them i find online. if i put the classes in my html it doesn't appear side by side .
what is wrong ith following css?
Apparently if i run the snippet here it works, but not if i test the page in chrome or edge

```css
.row:after{
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: inline;
}
[class*='col-']{
    padding: 15px;
    float: left;
}

.col-1{width: 8.33%};
.col-2{width: 16.66%};
.col-3{width: 25%};
.col-4{width: 33.3%};
.col-5{width: 41.66%};
.col-6{width: 50%};
.col-7{width: 58.33%};
.col-8{width: 66.66%};
.col-9{width: 75%};
.col-10{width: 83.33%};
.col-11{width: 91.66%};
.col-12{width: 100%};
```

```html
 <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4">
                <p>some text
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <p>some text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <p>some text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

sorry for the code mistakes at first

Comment: can u add the html code?

Comment: where is your html code

Comment: Do you have viewport setup?

Comment: Please add both html and css. if you add css forgot add html and  if u add html forgot to add css.

Answer (score 0):

```
you ar not adding both css and html for single file. Please take update jsfiddle
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5ga9j53r/